# SQL Server archiving table partitions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 which has a limitation when it comes to table partitions. Max limit is 1000 partition. SQL Server 2008 R2 does not support expanding the partition limit. I need to archive partitions to free up the production table. I will move partitions to a linked server where I will keep all archived data to save storage space from the D.W. I need some advice on the method to be used.

My thought is to create an un partitioned table on the linked server used for archiving, then move data and then delete partitions from the source table. Would this work using switch instead of copy - delete?

Would it be better to use partitions in the archive table too?

Comment: It almost goes without saying that upgrading to a supported version of SQL Server should be high on your priority list, for many reasons, including partition counts. _Almost_ goes without saying, but I kinda had to say it.

Comment: Your server is out of even extended support. Upgrading is extra attractive in this case because it would essentially solve your partition problem as well, at the cost of nothing more than a restore (and testing for backwards compatibility, admittedly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch a partition from the partition table to a standalone table, which happens in seconds. So, your solution can be:

```
 ALTER TABLE YourTable SWITCH PARTITION x TO ArchivingTable;

 -- Move data from the local ArchivingTable to your linked server (INSERT
 SELECT or bcp..)

 DROP TABLE ArchivingTable;
```

You an also merge existing partitions with aged data so free up partitions for new data.